# How to put Labels in a board?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to make a board game that is essentially a word searcher. I would like to create a board that would have labels like this:

```
    1  2  3  4 
1   q  w  e  r
2   p  o  t  t
3   q  y  h  f
```

I have already created a working code that would allow the user to input the number of rows and columns as well as the contents of the board itself. The problem is now that I can't seem to print it properly.Here is my working code:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
"""
Created on Tue Sep 17 00:40:13 2019

@author: Oscar Simon Velasco
"""
def get_words(n,words):
    global given_words
    count=1
    final=[given_words]
    while n!=count:
        count=count+1
        words=input('Enter a word:')
        final.append(words)
    return final

def sort_words(sorted__):
    global sorted_words
    bank={}
    x=sorted_words
    x.sort()
    W2=1
    print('Sorted words:')
    for y in x:
        print(y)
    for z in sorted_words:
        bank.update({W2:z})
        W2=W2+1
    print(bank)

def populate_board(RxC,letter):
    global letters_in_rows
    count=1
    final=[letters_in_rows]
    while RxC!=count:
        letter=input('Enter row:')
        count=count+1
        final.append(letter)
    print(final)
    return final

def print_board(a,row):
    b=[]
    for x in a:
        b.append(x)
    Labels_columns=range(1,row+1)
    Labels_rows=range(1,row+1)
    print(" ", end="")
    for c in Labels_columns :
        print(" " + str(c), end="")      
    print()       

    for i in range(1,row+1) :
        print(str(Labels_rows[i]), end="")
        for elt in b[i] :
            print(" " + str(elt), end="")
    print()                         



num_words=int(input('Enter desired number of words:'))   
given_words=input('Enter a word:')
sorted_words=get_words(num_words,given_words)

sort_words(sorted_words)

Number_rows=int(input('Enter number of rows and column:'))
letters_in_rows=str(input('Enter row:'))
board=populate_board(Number_rows,letters_in_rows)

print_board(letters_in_rows,Number_rows)
```

The function that supposedly prints the board is:

```
def print_board(a,row):
        b=[]
        for x in a:
            b.append(x)
        Labels_columns=range(1,row+1)
        Labels_rows=range(1,row+1)
        print(" ", end="")
        for c in Labels_columns :
            print(" " + str(c), end="")      
        print()       

        for i in range(1,row+1) :
            print(str(Labels_rows[i]), end="")
            for elt in b[i] :
                print(" " + str(elt), end="")
        print()
```

But I get the error 'IndexError: list index out of range' on line:

```
print(str(Labels_rows[i]), end="")
```

I can't understand why its doing it, knowingly I am still a newbie in python I am sure there must be an underlying cause here. I really need help on how to address this problem. THANK YOU IN ADVANCE!

Answer (score 0):

Just change it to `range(1, row)`. `row + 1` exceeds the length of the list.

Answer (score 0):

When you do this:

```
Labels_rows=range(1,row+1)
```

You don't have a list (just an FYI). You're binding a `Range` object to the variable name `Labels_rows`. Let's say `row` is 5. If you evaluate the contents, they look like this:

```
row = 5
Labels_rows = range(1, row+1)

print(*Labels_rows)
```

Output:

```
1 2 3 4 5
```

As expected.
In your for loop, you iterate over an identical range, but you use the values in that range as indecies for your `Labels_rows` range object. This means you will start iterating at index 1 (instead of 0, which does not result in an error, but is probably not deliberate), and your loop will try to run to index 5 (which would be the sixth element in your `Labels_rows` range object, which doesn't exist, hence the error).